# Enclose a word with other text using sed

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am trying append and prepend some text to each word using sed

My input is:

```
abc, def
```

I am expecting the output to be:

```
cast(abc as string), cast(def as string)
```

I am trying to do something similar to this:

```
test='abc, def'
echo "${test}"|sed 's/\</cast(a./g'|sed 's/\>/as string/g'
```

but this is giving something little different than expected

> castas string(aas string.abcas string, castas string(aas string.defas
>   string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = "cast(" $i " as string)"} 1' <<< "$test"

cast(abc as string), cast(def as string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test='abc, def'
echo "${test}"|sed -r 's/\w+/cast(& as string)/g'
```